# What is the PDF of gaussian plus laplacian noise?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, noise

Let $X=N_\sigma+L_b$ be the result of adding gaussian noise $N_\sigma$ centered at zero with scale $\sigma$ (std. dev.) and laplacian noise $L_b$ centered at zero with scale parameter $b$.

Is there a closed expression for the density function of $X$?

Comment: It can be expressed as an integral, but I don't think it has a closed-form solution.